# Truly no way to "generate" C# from byte[] containing IL with method body?

Tags: c#, roslyn, dynamic-invoke

I`ve being playing around with reversing of some obfuscated code out there and I have stumbled upon one tricky DLL that had a "method body" (IL code) in a byte[] array and was later on invoking it with dynamic invoke. Is analyzing MSIL the only way here?
How do you handle those?

I`ve spent hours researching online for tooling that would allow me to generate C# code (at least some basics) from IL in byte array. Is there truly none?

```
ldarg.0
ldarg.1     
add
```

Would be great if something existed out there, that could with some basic MSIL like above would generate a + b.

Comment: Best bet... https://www.telerik.com/blogs/justdecompile-engine-becomes-open-source

Comment: Don't forget to read the license/terms of service for the software you are examining.

Comment: It`s a crackme based on a malware. Good question though, does malware come with a license? Hmmm

Answer (score 0):

MZ64, hello and welcome to SO!

Unfortunately what you're asking is a decompiler service/API/tool and that is simply not built into .NET framework. You may want to check various third party solution for this.

Back in the days, *.NET Reflector* was #1 tool used for that. Today there are various tools, notably *dotPeek* - and Reflector should still be around. You will have to pay some money for most of them, but you may find a good free tool (I tried and failed).

However, if you want to take the IL code as plain text and just try to run it, then you should use built-in ILGenerator.Emit(). Easiest way I can think of should be to map your plain text to OpCode/variables, and emit your IL line by line. I don't know if it helps but in theory it should be possible.

Look here for an example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods

Comment: Follow up - would this allow me to generate C# from MSIL that is byte[] array?
 `byte[] arr = { ... 0x07, 0x08, 0x58 ... }; (...).DynamicInvoke(arr,....);`

What I mean is - from example above, can i just copy paste the bytes from the array and get them converted to C# by the tool? It should give me smth like: var1 + var2

Comment: Hm, it may work, never tried it though. Let me think about it a bit later, I'm busy now...

Comment: Well this was my question. I know that you can decompile msil to C#, dnspy does it very well and it is free. I know what dynamic invoke does and how to execute code from byte array - in fact the decompiled code does this.
The question is more about the second level. You have decompiled a dll that has MSIL in C# in byte[] and is calling dynamic invoke to execute it. -> how to decompile the code in byte[]? Is there a way? Basically i do not want to be doing manual analysis every time, I`m way quicker with C#. From the research that I did I could not find it anywhere. I thought maybe so knows.